# Draw rectangle (add_patch) in pylab mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using IPython in pylab mode (all functions at fingertip), and wanted to annotate certain plot, lets say `plot([1,3,2])` with rectangle `Rectangle((1,1),1,1)`

How can I draw a simple rectangle in this pylab mode, that is without using figure, axes, subplots... but reference just created plot in easiest possible way

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> in this pylab mode, that is without using figure, axes, subplots

Figues, axes, and subplots exist in the pylab framework too.  If I were using the pylab interface, I'd simply throw a `subplot(111)` in there and then use `sp.add_patch(Rectangle(etc))`.  But you can also grab the current axes/figure using `gca()` and `gcf()`:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> plot([1,3,2])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x102bc8950>]
>>> gca()
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x102790cd0>
>>> gca().add_patch(Rectangle((1,1),1,1))
<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x102790510>
>>> savefig("rect.png")
```

[image: line with rectangle]

The pylab approach is simple enough for very basic tasks, but doesn't scale as well up to more complex ones.

Comment: I didn't know about gca(). Thanks for the tip