# Custom plotting function does nothing the second time it's called from interactive prompt

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

So I tried to write a custom plotting function, which will behave like `plot`, in that you can call `subplot` and then calls to `new_plot` will be directed to that subplot, subsequent calls will plot over top of the original plot in different colors, etc.

However, when I try to plot multiple times from the interactive prompt in IPython, only the first call works.  If I call multiple times in a script or in a single command, it works.

I've stripped out everything except the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn


def new_plot():
    # get a figure/plot
    ax = plt.gca()

    # Plot the poles and set marker properties
    ax.plot(randn(10), randn(10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    new_plot()
    new_plot()
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    new_plot()
    new_plot()
    plt.show()
```

Running this script works fine, producing 2 plots of different colors on top of each other in each subplot.  Also, calling the function twice in one line of IPython interactive prompt works fine:

```
In [3]: new_plot()
   ...: new_plot()
   ...:
```

However, calling the function twice in a row does not work, only the first call succeeds, the rest fail silently:

```
In [4]: new_plot()

In [5]: new_plot()
```

Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Answer (score 1):

You are running into problems because you are combining the object oriented interface for Matplotlib with Pyplot, the state-machine environment. More information [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab) is also helpful.

You can make your example work by using Pyplot in `new_plot()`:

```
def new_plot():
    # Pyplot plot function
    plt.plot(randn(10), randn(10))
```

or by calling [draw()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.draw) from IPython interactive prompt after the calls to `new_plot()`.

Pyplot functions (`plt.plot` in this case) automatically redraw the figure but methods of the object oriented interface (`ax.plot`) do not.

Comment: but `pyplot.plot()`'s source code starts with `ax = gca()`.  so I should not try to copy that behavior?

Comment: No in general, I don't think you should copy that behavior. pyplot.plot() updates the figure with a call to draw_if_interactive which is not intended to be used outside of pyplot.

Comment: ok, is there a way to add patches without an `ax` object then? I was basing on things like http://stackoverflow.com/a/10665448/125507  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831549/get-matplotlib-color-cycle-state#comment19037056_13831816

Comment: calling `plt.draw()` at the end of the function seems to work.  anything wrong with that?