# matplotlib box on basemap map

Tags: graphics, matplotlib, coordinates, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to draw a box on a map *in relative coordinates* (i.e. 0 to 1). The reason is I have a colorbar on my map, but cannot see it clearly. I want a transparent box behind it. I've looked at adding patch Rectangles (see [Draw rectangle (add_patch) in pylab mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665163/draw-rectangle-add-patch-in-pylab-mode)), but that is in data coordinates, which is not easy to determine on this map. I also found axhspan, which uses relative coordinates for the x span, but data coordinates for the y span.

Is there a way to draw a box in a matplotlib axes object using relative coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to add a boxed text to a relative coordinates:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.text(0.5, 0.5,
    "Relative coords!",
    horizontalalignment = 'center',
    backgroundcolor = "white",
    verticalalignment = 'center',
    bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='green', alpha=0.65),
    transform = ax.transAxes,
    )

fig.savefig("mwe.png")
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit**:

To draw just a box given it's relative coordinates/dimensions with no text in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, zorder=1)

plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle(
    (0.4, 0.4), # lower left point of rectangle
    0.2, 0.2,   # width/height of rectangle
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    facecolor="white",
    edgecolor='green',
    alpha=0.65,
    zorder=2,
    ))

fig.savefig("mwe.png")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you do it without text and specify the width and height of the box?